# how to solve Networking or low-level protocol error?

Tags: block-production, solo-chain

I am running solochain so randomly my chain stop producing blocks and giving this error.

Every time when chain giving this error i need to stop and re-run the node.

substrate version using: v1.0.0

Can you please help why i am getting this error?

[image]

Comment: Next time, if you can, share the logs in text format so it is search friendly?

Comment: The best way to resolve this would be to attach a debugger and getting a stack trace. You can open a Substrate Github Issue with steps on how to replicate this.